# What happened to the Nautilus feature "Create Link" in Ubuntu 16.10 and newer?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I was surprised to see that the context menu entry "Make Link" (keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) in Nautilus doesn't seem to exist anymore. It used to appear upon right mouse click on a file or folder and allowed the user to create a symbolic link.

Comment: @cl-netbox No problem. The question is search-able anyway :)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This answer is suitable for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, since Ubuntu 16.10 the feature preference has changed. The feature still exists ... it just has to be activated. Open Nautilus and go to **Preferences** -> **Behavior**.

Enable the option **"Show action to create symbolic links"**. Now you have the **"Create Link"** context menu entry in Nautilus ... Note : The keyboard shortcut changed from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

[image: Nautilus Preferences]

Comment: What version of Nautilus it is?

Comment: Can't find the option on Nautilu 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1

Comment: FYI - Although this option is selected, the context menu still does not appear.

Comment: I wish I'd known about that a few months ago. I had to set up a lot of symbolic links lately using `ln`. :-)

Comment: In the latest version the shortcut for creating a link to the currently selected file is Ctrl+Shift+M while the shortcut to create a link to a copied file is Ctrl+M