# How to create symbolic link in Files (Nautilus) without using command line?

Tags: nautilus, gnome-shell

I would like to create a link to a directory or file.
How can this be done using Files (Nautilus)?

I did not see a right-click context menu option to do this.

I know could do it by using the `ln -s` command, but I am looking for a way to do this using keyboard shortcuts or mouse clicks.

Comment: The mouse methods should still work: https://askubuntu.com/a/941711/158442

Comment: @muru, I'm going to mark this as solved by https://askubuntu.com/questions/843150/what-happened-to-the-nautilus-feature-create-link-in-ubuntu-16-10-and-newer. But your answer also works, so I have two options!