# How to create file shortcuts?

Tags: shortcuts

I want to add a shortcut to a file in another directory (where it isn't located). How do I do that? I see no option to do so after right clicking the respective file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a soft or symbolic link?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link) or [What happened to the Nautilus feature “Create Link” in Ubuntu 16.10 and newer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843150/what-happened-to-the-nautilus-feature-create-link-in-ubuntu-16-10-and-newer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using terminal command:

```
ln -s filepath linkpath
```

You can also hold `Shift + Ctrl` and drag a file where you want to make a shortcut.

If you want executables then you need `*.desktop` file. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244820/308766) is a link how to use it. Do not forget to add permissions for executing. If you want this shortcut to be shown in applications menu put desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications`.